# C++ Word guessing game

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to make a part of the game hangman, where the user inputs a letter and then a loop check for that letter in a random array. If the letter is found, it then couts a changed array including now that letter and offers the user to again, input another letter. It seems for loops are not working since the program doesnt scan the whole array for ever letter inputted. How can I fix this?

```
int main(){

string guess[25];
string password[5];
srand((unsigned)time(0));

string letters[5] = {"_ ","_ ","_ ","_ ","_ "};
char array[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','r','s','t','u','v','z'};

for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++){
    int g = rand() % 24;
    password[r] = array[g];
}

cout << endl;

     for(int z = 0; z < 25; z++){

    cout << "Enter Letter: " << endl;
    cin >> guess[z];

    for(int b = 0; b < 5; b++){
        if(uguess[z] == password[b]){
            letters[b] = guess[b];
            cout << letters[b];
        }else{
            cout << letters[b];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks
It always says that the word being guessed if asdfg, but it messes it up very badly, as in doesn't always show the letter, even if it has been guessed, it shows it later.

Comment: can you explain the downvotes?

Comment: Change `char array[26] ....` to `const char * const array = "abcdef....` - Easier to read and will be in not on the stack

Comment: It's hard to see what is happening (it might help a bit if your variable names were in English). Although I suspect you may mean `crke[b] = ugib[z]`, not `crke[b] = ugib[b]`.

Comment: @forkul It works now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
crke[b] = ugib[b];
```

This line should be:

```
crke[b] = ugib[z];
```

You might want to consider investing some time in learning how to use a debugger, which would've helped you figure it out.